# NativeAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId:

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, admob, google-ads-api

I am trying to add google native ads in my flutter app using this library

> https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads

i am getting this error:

```
\[log\] NativeAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: _-SvZbabD5e-3LUP4oaxkAs, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: \[AdapterResponseInfo(adapterClassName: com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter, latencyMillis: 83, description: {
"Adapter": "com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter",
"Latency": 83,
"Ad Source Name": "Reservation campaign",
"Ad Source ID": "7068401028668408324",
"Ad Source Instance Name": "\[DevRel\] \[DO NOT EDIT\] Native Ads Campaign",
"Ad Source Instance ID": "3518433842871043",
"Credentials": {
"pubid": "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110/cak=no_cache&cadc=c3&caqid=_-SvZfiWDr-FmsMPtMWtgAM",
"campaign_id": "12584073087"
},
"Ad Error": {
"Code": 0,
"Message": "Internal error.",
"Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
"Cause": "null"
}
}, adUnitMapping: {pubid: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110/cak=no_cache&cadc=c3&caqid=\_-SvZfiWDr-FmsMPtMWtgAM, campaign_id: 12584073087}, adError: AdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error.), adSourceName: Reservation campaign, adSourceId: 7068401028668408324, adSourceInstanceName: \[DevRel\] \[DO NOT EDIT\] Native Ads Campaign, adSourceInstanceId: 3518433842871043)\], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {mediation_group_name: Campaign})
```

Minimal Code to Reproduce

Native Controller:

```dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

class NativeAdController extends GetxController {
  NativeAd? ad;
  final adLoaded = false.obs;
}
```

Ad Helper:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import '../controllers/controller_native_ads.dart';

class AdHelper {
  static Future<void> initAds() async {
    await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  }

  void loadInterstitialAd({required VoidCallback onComplete}) {
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712',
      request: const AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        // Called when an ad is successfully received.
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          ad.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
            onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
              onComplete();
            },
            onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) {
              log(error.toString());
            },
            onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
              log("Full Screen");
            },
          );
          log('This is the $ad loaded.');
        },
        // Called when an ad request failed.
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          log('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  static NativeAd loadNativeAd({required NativeAdController nativeAdController}) {
    return NativeAd(
      adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110',
      listener: NativeAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (ad) {
          log('$NativeAd loaded.');
          nativeAdController.adLoaded.value = true;
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
          log('$NativeAd failed to load: $error');
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
      request: const AdRequest(),
      // Styling
      nativeTemplateStyle: NativeTemplateStyle(
        templateType: TemplateType.small,
      ),
    )..load();
  }
}
```

Test Screen:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../controllers/controller_native_ads.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  TestScreen({super.key});

  final adController = Get.put(NativeAdController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    adController.ad = AdHelper.loadNativeAd(nativeAdController: adController);

    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: adController.ad != null && adController.adLoaded.isTrue
          ? SafeArea(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 80,
                child: AdWidget(ad: adController.ad!),
              ),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }
}
```

I am using test id provided by official google docs [flutter-quick-start](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/quick-start)

Can anyone explain me why this error occurs?